# Java web app with Paypal - where to put signature?

Tags: java, paypal

I need to integrate paypal in my java web app (JSF). I could make successfully an API call like in the sample app in **rest-api-sdk-0.7.0**. When I replace the Credentials (clientSecret,clientID) in the sdk_config.properties with my own from the sandbox, I get an error:

```
SEVERE: Error code : 401 with response : {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Invalid client credentials"}
```

This happend when trying to get an access token. client ID and secret are correct. I tested it with **curl** and got **ACK=Success**. 
Is this related to the fact, that the signature is not used? Where should I put the signature?

What should I consider too, when going live? A part from changing the service.EndPoint?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong credentials: **Classic TEST API credentials**! The right credentials are **REST API credentials**. This is really badly managed in the developer website! Under Applications u see "My apps" and "Sandbox accounts". I would expect to find everything in "Sandbox accounts".